# unknown http.Transport field 'ExpectContinueTimeout' in struct literal in GO

Tags: http, go, timeout

In my GO project I am getting an error in `transport.go` file as,

> mygo/testkit/pkg/http
>
> ## mygo/testkit/pkg/http pkg\http\transport.go:93: unknown http.Transport field 'ExpectContinueTimeout' in struct literal

Here is my `newDefaultTransport()` function, which gives the error in `transport.go`.

```
func newDefaultTransport() *http.Transport {
    return &http.Transport{

        DisableCompression: disableCompression,    
        DisableKeepAlives:   defaultDisableKeepAlives,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: defaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: defaultResponseHeaderTimeout,

        ExpectContinueTimeout: defaultExpectContinueTimeout,

        TLSHandshakeTimeout: defaultTLSHandshakeTimeout,
        TLSClientConfig:     newTLSClientConfig(),    
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        Dial: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return NewTimeoutConnDial(network, addr, TCPDialTimeout, TCPKeepAlive, defaultIdleTimeout)
        },
    }
}
```

And I am getting the error at this line,

```
ExpectContinueTimeout: defaultExpectContinueTimeout,
```

What will be the reason for this error? How to solve this? I am new to this `GO` framework.

Comment: Does the compile error go away after removing that line? It looks correct to me, but perhaps there's a hidden or unicode sneaking in there?

Comment: @KevinDeenanauth : If I remove or comment this line, then its not giving any compile error.

Comment: No clue - it's a valid field: https://play.golang.org/p/szXUKuYScx

Comment: is defaultExpectContinueTimeout defined correctly, compiler gives such err:  "unknown X field 'Y' in struct literal when Y not defined.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using gccgo? If so, can you reproduce the problem with gc?

Answer (score 1):

The [ExpectContinueTimeout](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport.ExpectContinueTimeout) field was added in Go 1.6. Upgrade your version of Go.